Is this a bipolar capacitor?
What kind of capacitor is this? It is from a clock. I know that it is 47 µF/6 V, but I don't know if it is a bipolar capacitor or normal capacitor.



Thank you

What capacitor are you referring to? The variable one? That's definitely nowhere near 47 μF, but it is indeed non-polarized.

@Hearth No, the 47 or 4.7 uF, 6V one. Brown cylinder. Made by Roederstein (ROE). Which does not have polarization markings like similar polarized capacitors from ROE do have.

@Justme Ah, that looked more like an inductor to me; I've not seen a capacitor in a package like that before.

yes, the brown one. it does not have any markings. so probably is non-polarized capacitor ?

Yes, I believe so. For example, here is a higher value one in an eBay listing, also in Roderstein's EKU series and claimed by the seller to be bipolar:

I've seen parts like this behind the dashboard of a 1980s German car.

Thank you. purely informative if there is a way to check if this is bipolar or not. maybe with multimeter ? if not, I will buy one new non-polarized capacitor to replace this old one, because the clock stopped to work. and the clock is old 40 years...

If the cap is bad it will have (most likely) high ESR, which most multimeters won't measure. It's not easy to see if the cap is bipolar - polarized ones behave similarly at low reverse voltages, but the lack of polarity markings is a sure 'tell'. Two 100uF caps in inverse series (+ to + or - to -) should be an okay substitute.
